# Add column to dataframe based on corresponding values of two row values from another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'X1':[2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5], 
                'X2':[10,20,70,80,10,20,70,80,50,70,80,60,70,80,90], 
                'X3':[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]})


     X1  X2  X3
0    2  10   0
1    2  20   1
2    2  70   0
3    2  80   1
4    3  10   1
5    3  20   1
6    3  70   1
7    3  80   0
8    4  50   0
9    4  70   0
10   4  80   1
11   5  60   1
12   5  70   0
13   5  80   0
14   5  90   0
```

> and the other one is df2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X1':[2,3,3,4,5,5,5], 
                'X2':[10,20,70,50,60,70,80]})

   X1  X2
0   2  10
1   3  20
2   3  70
3   4  50
4   5  60
5   5  70
6   5  80
```

I need to find the corresponding X3 values for df2 based on the value of X1 and X2 in each row of df1.The results should be something like the following:

```
    X1  X2  X3
0   2  10   0
1   3  20   1
2   3  70   1
3   4  50   0
4   5  60   1
5   5  70   0
6   5  80   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

  - If multiple values are given to the `on=` parameter, the `other` DataFrame must have a MultiIndex, so [`.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) on `df1`.

```py
df2 = df2.join(df1.set_index(['X1', 'X2']), on=['X1', 'X2'])

# display(df2)
   X1  X2  X3
0   2  10   0
1   3  20   1
2   3  70   1
3   4  50   0
4   5  60   1
5   5  70   0
6   5  80   0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.merge`:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1, on=["X1", "X2"])
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
   X1  X2  X3
0   2  10   0
1   3  20   1
2   3  70   1
3   4  50   0
4   5  60   1
5   5  70   0
6   5  80   0
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. what if df1 has other columns such as X4, X5, .. and I just need df2 with X1, X2, and X3 columns.